# Hacer if en una sola línea

Tags: c#, operador-ternario

¿Como haríais el siguiente código en una línea con ? y :?

```
if (cVideos.Checked) 
{
    Tableta.TabPages.Add(TabVideos)
}
else
{
    Tableta.TabPages.Remove(TabVideos);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El **operador condicional ?:**, también conocido como **operador condicional ternario**, evalúa una expresión booleana y devuelve el resultado de una de las dos expresiones, en función de que la expresión booleana se evalúe como **true** o **false**, ejemplo:

```
string resultado = (nota > 59) ? "Aprobado" : "Suspenso";
```

Si **nota** es mayor que **59** entonces en la **variable resultado** se almacena el valor **"Aprobado"**, sino, se almacena el valor **"Suspenso"**.

En otras palabras, para poder usar el **operador ternario** debe haber una asignación en una variable dependiendo del resultado que devuelve la expresión que se evalúa, en este caso se le asigna a la **variable resultado** el valor **"Aprobado"** o **"Suspenso"** en dependencia de la expresion booleana que se evalúa:

```
(nota > 59)
```

En tu ejemplo específico no se puede usar el **operador ternario**, porque no hay ninguna asignación en otra variable, no te hace falta.

No es correcto poner:

```
cVideos.Cheked ? Tableta.TabPages.Add(TabVideos) : Tableta.TabPages.Remove(TabVideos);
```

Por tanto lo correcto es usar el **bloque if-else**.

Answer (score 0):

Depende del contexto. Puedes añadir: `Tableta.TabPages.Add(TabVideos)` por defecto.

Y luego decir:

```
if (cVideos.Checked) {
            Tableta.TabPages.Remove(TabVideos); }
```

Answer (score -1):

Lo primero que debes conocer es la estructura que tiene dicha sentencia:

`condicion? operacion_1 : operacion_2`

Dicho lo cual, asignando de tu código:

`condicion` = cVideos.Checked

`operacion_1` =  Tableta.TabPages.Add(TabVideos)

`operacion_2` = Tableta.TabPages.Remove(TabVideos);

Simplemente queda de la siguiente manera:

```
cVideos.Cheked ? Tableta.TabPages.Add(TabVideos) : Tableta.TabPages.Remove(TabVideos);
```

**Posible duda futura**

Si en algún momento te preguntas cómo puedes hacer esto asignando el valor de las operaciones a una variable, la anterior instrucción la puedes asignar a una variable directamente del modo:

```
VARIABLE = cVideos.Cheked ? Tableta.TabPages.Add(TabVideos) : Tableta.TabPages.Remove(TabVideos);
```

Comment: me parece que eso no se puede hacer, lo probaste?

Comment: Hola Buenas,
Ambas opciones eran las que probaba yo, pero daban error, por tanto, no son correctas

Comment: No, pero sé que es posible. Aquí está la documentación https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

Comment: Me parece que tu respuesta no es correcta, revisa bien.

Comment: Lamentablemente el operador condicional ternario solo se puede usar para asignar a una variable :(